# What does Haissam Haqqani say in episode 10 of season 4?

Tags: homeland

Before plunging the knife into Fara Sherazi in *Homeland* S04E10, Haissam says something in Arabic/Urdu that sounds like "cum kere fish". What does he say and what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember looking it up after watching this and apparently (unless I've been misled) he said '*Tum kafir*', which is bad Urdu\Kurdish for '*You infidel*' (though in this context, it's more like a profane '*blood traitor*'). [Here's some info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafir) about this term.

**EDIT**: Just re-listened to this and it does sound like '*Kum kafish*'. However, [the actor is Turkish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numan_Acar) and *Kafir* is pronounced (or sounds to Westerners, anyway) like *Kafish* of *Kafirsh* in Turkish.

Answer (score 11):

I tweeted Numan Acar who amazingly [tweeted back](https://twitter.com/NumanAcar_/status/543547122541682688) with an answer to the question.

> **[@NumanAcar_](https://twitter.com/NumanAcar_):** *Numan, what did you say to Fara ( Nazanine) before you stabbed her??*
>
> **[@CandiceSTurner:](https://twitter.com/CandiceSTurner)**  ***Haqqani said to her: You traitor!***

---

Screenshot:

[image: Twitter exchange]

Comment: Wow, great to know (and very nice of him). Do you happen to have a link or a screengrab?

Comment: [twitter-tweet](https://twitter.com/NumanAcar_/status/543547122541682688)

Answer (score 0):

"Tum kafir" is not you traitor, tum kafir means you non believer basically in Islam kafir is non believer or basically an abuser of Islam .